# How to retrieve data when component is loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I've got a list of projects, and I want to display the name of the clicked project in a modal on the next page, when I click on one of them, it loads without problem and displays the association name in my modal.

But the problem comes when I reload this project page, it throws an error "Cannot read property 'asso_id' of undefined""

I get the project by it's id with a getter to retrieve the asso_id in the project object, then use this asso_id with my association by id getter to get the related association.

I think it's because my component doesn't retrieve the AssociationTitle soon enough.

Here is my code

```
 computed: {
      "getProjectById",
      "getAssociationById"
    ]),
    project() {
      const projectId = this.$route.params.id;
      return this.getProjectById(projectId);
    },
    associationTitle() {
      const project = this.project;
      const association = this.getAssociationById(project.asso_id);

      return association.title;
    }
  }
```

```
 getters: {
    getProjects: state => {
      return state.projects = [...ProjectData.ProjectData];
    },
    getProjectById: state => id => {
      return state.projects.find(project => project._id === id);
    },
    getAssociations: state => {
      return state.associations = [...AssociationData.AssociationData];
    },
    getAssociationById: state => id => {
      state.associations = [...AssociationData.AssociationData];
      return state.associations.find(association => association._id === id);
    }
  }
```

```
<v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title> {{ associationTitle }} </v-card-title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're guessing it right. You can just check if you have the project e.g.

```
 associationTitle() {
      const project = this.project;
      const title = project ? this.getAssociationById(project.asso_id).title : '';
      // or typeof project !== 'undefined' or something similar
      return title;
    }
```